# Program is executing but AT commands not showing in serial monitor

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, gsm, communication, command-line

My purpose was to send SMS using [GSM SIM800L coreboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daxN0.jpg)  and Arduino UNO. Here is the code

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//Create a software serial object to communicate with SIM800L
SoftwareSerial mySerial(3, 2); //SIM800L Tx & Rx is connected to Arduino #3 & #2

void setup()
{
  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM800L
  mySerial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("Initializing..."); 
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT"); //Once the handshake test is successful, it will back to OK
  updateSerial();

  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1"); // Configuring TEXT mode
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+ZZxxxxxxxxx\"");//change ZZ with country code and xxxxxxxxxxx with phone number to sms
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.print("TEST"); //text content
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.write(26);
}

void loop()
{
}

void updateSerial()
{
  delay(500);
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
  }
  while(mySerial.available()) 
  {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
  }
}
```

And here is the serial monitor output

```
 22:31:19.430 -> Initializing...
```

However, when I run the code, I get the text message to my mobile phone, but [I can't see any AT commands in the serial monitor. It only outputs "Initializing..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOSR7.png) .
All the connections and baud rates are okay, checked a thousand times. Has connected 2A, 4.4v power supply to the GSM coreboard and shorten the wires, and sho No bad soldering joints. GSM module red led flash per 3 seconds. And again, I'm getting the text message to my phone. So that means the problem is with the Arduino serial monitor or code, not in the hardware. I need to see AT commands because I need to put more commands through the serial monitor, I tried typing and click send, But it's not showing anything. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have tried a lower baud rate? ... that is one of the first things to try when debugging serial comm

Comment: Yes, I have tried many baud rates, 4800, 9600, also higher baud rates